# function returning limited cursor

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to ask how can I return cursor to limited table?
I mean a function which takes (if absolute position, if forward or backward, how many records, absolute position) and works as fetch absolute + forward.
I've tried this, but didn't work.

```
drop function func(text,text,integer,integer);
create function func(text,text,integer,integer=0) returns refcursor as '
declare
    ref refcursor;
begin
    open ref for select * from test;
    if $1="A" then
        if $2="F" then
            move absolute $4 in ref;
            return fetch forward $3 from ref;   
        elseif $2="B"
            move absolute $4 in ref;
            return fetch backward $3 from ref;
        end if;
    elseif $1="B" then
        if $2="F" then
            return fetch forward $3 from ref;
        elseif $2="B"
            return fetch backward $3 from ref;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
'language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to manipulate the cursor, I think you'll probably need to apply these constraints in the query itself.

I'm assuming that your real query would have an `ORDER BY` clause, as the `FETCH` direction is fairly meaningless without it. Also, the "is absolute" parameter doesn't seem to serve much purpose, as specifying `'B'` is the same as specifying `'A'` with position `0`, so you should be able to remove it.

The end result would be something like this:

```
create or replace function func(dir text, num integer, pos integer=0) returns refcursor as $$
declare
  ref refcursor;
begin
   open ref for execute
     ' select * from test '
     ' order by x ' || case dir when 'F' then 'ASC' when 'B' then 'DESC' end ||
     ' limit ' || num ||
     ' offset ' || pos;
   return ref;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```